Logging tuple lvalue and const or not
This is just a code written for testing. I just want to print the lvalue and const information of the given tuple. It works without any errors except the print function. Since the code is short and very understandable, I think there is no need for additional explanation.
Can you help me understand why the code is not working and what I should do to fix it?
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Parameters>
struct Test {
    Test(Parameters&&... params): parameters_{std::forward<Parameters>(params)...} {}
    std::tuple<Parameters...> parameters_;
    
    void print() {
        if ( std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(std::get<0>)(parameters_)>::value ) {
            std::cout << "lvalue ref\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "rvalue ref\n";
        }
        
        if ( std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<0>)(parameters_)>>::value ) {
            std::cout << "const\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "non const\n";
        }  
    }
};


int main() {
    Test<int, float> t{1, 2.2};
t.print();
    return 0;
}


Your code doesn't compile because when you use is_lvalue_reference and is_const, the parenthesis are not correctly located. Actually, you have to use std::get<T> like a regular function, where the argument is the object (e.g. a std::tuple) you want to get the first item from. So, you have to write something like std::get<0>(parameters_).
Then, once you got the first item of your std::tuple, you can indeed retrieve its type with decltype.
Here is a working code. Note that one can use using in order to make the code more readable. Since you didn't precise a c++ standard, I assume that you could also use _v extensions for type traits, which makes also the code clearer.
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Parameters>
struct Test {
    Test(Parameters&&... params): parameters_{std::forward<Parameters>(params)...} {}
    std::tuple<Parameters...> parameters_;

    void print() {

    using type = decltype(std::get<0>(parameters_));

        if ( std::is_lvalue_reference_v<type>) {
            std::cout << "lvalue ref\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "rvalue ref\n";
        }
        
        if ( std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<type>>) {
            std::cout << "const\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "non const\n";
        }  
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<int, float> t{1, 2.2};
t.print();
    return 0;
}

Demo

Test<int&&, float> t{1, 2.2};. it is printting lvalue ref. Any idea?

@QweQwe • instead of using type = decltype(std::get<0>(parameters_)); which is the type of that the get returns, try using type = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Parameters...>>;.

@QweQwe, what you print is the type  of the parameters_ field (or at least one part of it), which is something that has a name and therefore is a left reference. You can have a look here in particular the paragraph on Rvalue references; you can see how the different overloads of the f function work, in particular when you call it with an object such as int&& x = 1;. In other words, it is normal that you get a left reference as the result of your snippet.
